# R summarize_if more complex functions to multiple columns

Tags: r, tidyverse

Hi I am looking for an elegant solution ideally combination dplyr&purr.

I will group data by id and then I have 4 numeric columns and I want to apply to all of these
columns sum function. Additionally I want to apply to this 4 numeric columns conditional sum based on diff column.

So let' say to be specific I want from summarize sum of all 4 columns, sum of all 4 columns where diff<11, sum of all columns where diff<21

I started with this but got stucked

```
df%>%group_by(id)%>%summarise_if(is.numeric,.funs = (sum,~sum(.[diff<11])) 


    df<-structure(list(id = c(10274565, 10274449, 10274449, 10274449, 
10274565, 10274557, 10274557, 10274449, 10274565, 10274565, 10274565, 
10274557, 10274565, 10274557, 10274557, 10274557, 10274557, 10274557, 
10274557, 10274449, 10274449), d_amt = c(70L, 52L, 47L, 31L, 
100L, 17L, 74L, 54L, 83L, 90L, 76L, 98L, 73L, 49L, 81L, 82L, 
80L, 24L, 30L, 21L, 43L), d_cnt = c(3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L), w_amt = c(74L, 
16L, 20L, 73L, 22L, 11L, 61L, 90L, 78L, 94L, 64L, 58L, 84L, 15L, 
42L, 31L, 53L, 92L, 76L, 14L, 65L), w_cnt = c(4L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 
5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 
1L), diff = structure(c(43, 30, 20, 16, 22, 57, 50, 40, 64, 51, 
50, 8, 88, 85, 79, 43, 28, 22, 17, 13, 3), class = "difftime", units = "days")), row.names = c(NA, 
-21L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(
    across(
      where(is.integer),
      list(below11 = ~ sum(.[diff < 11]),
           below21 = ~ sum(.[diff < 21]))
    )
  )
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 9
        id d_amt_below11 d_amt_below21 d_cnt_below11 d_cnt_below21 w_amt_below11 w_amt_below21 w_cnt_below11 w_cnt_below21
     <dbl>         <int>         <int>         <int>         <int>         <int>         <int>         <int>         <int>
1 10274449            43           142             5            15            65           172             1             6
2 10274557            98           128             3             7            58           134             1             5
3 10274565             0             0             0             0             0             0             0             0
```

Note that the columns in your example appear to be `integer`, therefore the `is.integer` part.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~sum(.[diff < 11])))

#        id d_amt d_cnt w_amt w_cnt
#     <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1 10274449    43     5    65     1
#2 10274557    98     3    58     1
#3 10274565     0     0     0     0
```

Or if you are using older version of `dplyr` :

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise_if(is.numeric, ~sum(.[diff < 11]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could group by the `diff` column and then summarise over groups:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(dif_cat = case_when(diff < 11 ~ "<11",
                             diff < 22 ~ "<22",
                             TRUE ~ ">=22")) %>% 
  group_by(id, dif_cat) %>% 
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~sum(.)))


# A tibble: 7 x 6
# Groups:   id [3]
        id dif_cat d_amt d_cnt w_amt w_cnt
     <dbl> <chr>   <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 10274449 <11        43     5    65     1
2 10274449 <22        99    10   107     5
3 10274449 >=22      106     7   106     8
4 10274557 <11        98     3    58     1
5 10274557 <22        30     4    76     4
6 10274557 >=22      407    16   305    17
7 10274565 >=22      492    20   416    23
```

Comment: well actually these ranges are allowed to overlapp so it is diff betwenn 0 and 11, diff between 0 and 21 ...but this is usefull anyways in other scenarios